# Redundant mov operations if you passing variable by reference

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization, compiler-optimization

Is there any reason why modern C++ compilers can't optimize redundant **mov** instruction if you changing variable passed by reference?

Slow: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2Bmidk

Redundant mov:

```
10:        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
```

Fast: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/u3GMLx

Why compiler just don't store **begin_** variable in CPU register and write it to memory in the end of function?

Comment: That's the calling convention.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, but there's no calls involved?(everything inlined)

Comment: This is not an easy optimization: the compiler would have to prove that the qword at `rdi` and any of the bytes read from the charstream never overlap

Comment: @harold Nice catch, you should make an answer out of it.

Comment: @harold Seems like you're right: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_wm_zO

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it may be invalid optimisation. What if `begin_` equals to `this` i.e address of `CharStream` itself (and it's valid to read bytes of any object using `char*`)? In that case after first read `CharStream` will change and so may the value of range [begin; end)

To avoid this you may do one of the following:

- accept CharStream by value (so that it's address is unique and doesn't coincide with any `char*`): https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QfOUwW (note the change in behaviour. You'll need to return the stream if you need modifications)
- use another type instead of `char` so that it can't alias with `CharStream`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2_gREf (beware, it might be undefined to read your data using `Byte*` instead of `char*` because it's `some_other_type*` originally)

Comment: Note that passing by value changes the behavior of the code -- it no longer modifies the original `CharStream` passed to `get_hash`

Comment: How about using `size_t get_hash(CharStream & __restrict__ stream, size_t length)`? Rather than making a copy, it assures the compiler that this pointer isn't being used somewhere else, allowing additional optimization.